# Как изменить цвет рандомной кнопки?

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажав на рандомную кнопку, цвет рандомной кнопки должен измениться.

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            button1.BackColor = Color.Coral;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            button2_Click(sender, e);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button2.BackColor = Color.Black;
        }
```

После нажатия на кнопку 1, кнопка 2 меняет цвет. А мне необходимо поменять цвет рандомной кнопки. После этого, я нажимаю на эту кнопку и опять какая-то рандомная кнопка меняет цвет

Comment: Button[] b = new Button[9];
b[0] = button1;
...
b[9] = button9;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возьмите все кнопки на форме:

```
IEnumerable<Button> _formButtons = this.Controls.OfType<Button>();
```

После этого можно присвоить один обработчик на все эти кнопки:

```
foreach(Button btn in _formButtons)
{
   btn.Click += btn_Click;
}
```

И уже в хэндлере реализовать нужную вам логику:

```
void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Random random = new Random();
   int index = random.Next(0, _formButtons.Count());
   Button randomBtn = _formButtons.ElementAt(index);
   randomBtn.BackColor = "нужный_вам_цвет";
}
```

Comment: Все работает, но срабатывает один раз. Это можно исправить?

Comment: добавьте подписку на события в Form_Load